# Custom import xml example needed

Tags: magento2

Could any1 please tell on how to achieve custom csv product import.

I need to save the product ids on import to my custom table.

Custom table should have only product_id column.

i followed this link: http://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/magento-2-programming-implement-import-with-import-xml

But i face issue in **getEntityTypeCode()**

I need a full working example.